# How does this factor to 6(1-ln6)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

-6(ln6)+6

I got....

6(-1(ln6)

shouldn't the 1 be negative not the ln6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the part of the expression when we add $6$; when you factor out $6$ from each term, you're left with:

$$-6\cdot (\ln (6)) + 6 = 6\cdot\Big ((-1)\ln(6) + 1\Big) = 6\cdot \Big(-\ln(6) + 1\Big) = 6\cdot\Big(1 - \ln(6)\Big)$$

Comment: Short and sweet - those are nice! +1

Answer (score 1):

Let's do a similar example...

$$-6 \cdot \ln (5)  + 6 \cdot 1 = 6 \cdot (-1 \cdot \ln(5) + 1) = 6(-\ln(5) +1) = 6(1-\ln(5))$$